# how I get the index of an array with a NSDictionary for key in swift?

Tags: swift, ios8

I have this array:

```
var cars : NSArray = [
    ["name":"Dayatona", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Viper", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"F344", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Dayatona", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Cobra", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Dayatona", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"GT500", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"]
]
```

i need to get the "name" of each item here:

```
func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

            cell.textLabel?.text = cars["name"]
    }
```

Comment: try like this ==> var cars: [[String:String]] = [ ... ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cars[indexPath.row].valueForKey(“name”)
```

You store a dictionary in a array.

```
cars[indexPath.row]
```

Is used to get the dictionary in the array that is corresponding to the row in the `UITableView`

```
.valueForKey(“name”)
```

Is used to get the `name` out of the dictionary

EDIT:

```
var cars : NSArray = [
  ["name":"Dayatona", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Viper", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"F344", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Dayatona", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Cobra", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"Dayatona", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"],["name":"GT500", "marca":"Dodge","ano":"1969"]
]

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

  println(cars[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name"))
}


configureCell(UITableViewCell(), atIndexPath: NSIndexPath(forRow: 1, inSection: 1))
```

Is used for testing (Swift 1.2) and is confirmed to work

Comment: _?? is not convertible to String

Comment: I have this error if I write   "cell.textLabel?.text = cars[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name")"   but if I write "println(cars[indexPath.row].valueForKey("name"))"   this work!